# php-resque: How to kill a specific job?

Tags: php, php-resque

I am using the [php-resque](https://github.com/chrisboulton/php-resque) library and jobs can be created and tracked using the following code.

```
$token = Resque::enqueue('queue', 'Job', NULL, true);

$statusTracker = new Resque_Job_Status($token);
$status = $statusTracker->get();
```

But given the token returned by the `enqueue` method, how can the job be stopped?

I have found [this](https://github.com/chrisboulton/php-resque/issues/209) on the project page, but it doesn't use the job token to stop a job, it uses the worker id instead.

Considering that I might have more than one worker active, how can I found the worker id that is doing the requested job?

Comment: What do you mean by 'be stopped', do you mean you do not want to run the job as in dequeueing?

Comment: Well, yes, but dequeuing works even if the worker has already started the job? Or it works only with jobs that are yet to be executed?

Comment: You can throw a exception in the job so it will be marked as 'failed'. See: https://github.com/chrisboulton/php-resque#onfailure

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't specified that I don't want to stop the job from inside. The use case is that the user has launched a long time job and then wants to stop it. How can I give this functionality using resque?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Resqueue doesn't support 'aborting' or 'stopping' jobs. **But** if you can somehow manage to save the cancel action in some sort of DB you'll be fine. You can do a additional check in the performAction(). Something like;

```
class My_Job {
    public function perform() {
        $wasCanceled = true;
        if( $wasCanceled ) {
            throw new Exception("Job was cancelled");
        }

        // Perform job stuff.
    }
}
```

Last but not least; this might not always work when jobs are already executed before the cancellation was done..

Comment: That could work, but if there's a lot of stuff to in my perform method, there should be a check near each action performed (since the cancel operation could be performed anytime).

Comment: I would recommend you to do small jobs each time; and if you do not want that, just create an additional function which checks the cancellation-action, so you would only have to call $this->wasCanceled() a couple of times!